# How can you determine if a laptop hard drive is 2.5" or 1.8"?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

How can you determine if a laptop hard drive is 2.5" or 1.8"?

For example, wdc wd1600bevt-22zct0

Comment: Just google this serial, and you'll find lots of places where it's sold, and specs are also given.

Comment: Well, the first link on a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wd1600bevt-22zct0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) gives "Buy WD WD1600BEVT-22ZCT0 WD 160GB SATA 2.5in 5400RPM 9.5mm 8MB" so a pretty safe bet it is 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the device, you can just measure the width along the shorter dimension - the size that has the connector.  A 2.5 hard drive is actually about 2.7 inches, and a 1.8 hard drive is about 2.1 inches.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_drive_form_factors

You can also look at the connector.  Normal SATA connectors are used for 2.5 and 3.5, but a micro SATA connector is required for the 1.8 .  You can find some converters at Amazon. I have never seen a native micro SATA connector inside a PC.  Laptops usually have enough horizontal space to fit a 2.5 hard drive.  The only place I've ever seen a 1.8 was in a 2000s-era digital camera.

Comment: looks like samsung and toshiba are sometimes 1.8" https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100007637%20600003491 .  but i see yeah most laptops are still 2.5" . Also I notice your link names the 1.8" form factor as obsolete https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_drive_form_factors which is good to know so even toshiba might not do 1.8" anymore

Comment: 1.8" disks actually sound like something from IDE era rather than SATA; they would probably have used the CompactFlash / PCMCIA style connector. (CF itself can use IDE so it's the right pin count, and many laptops had PCMCIA in them anyway...)